# How to count number of visiorts to django website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, session

I am working on Django web application and i need to count number of visitors to my page here is my code which count every visit to home page as new visit despite of session.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class PageView(models.Model):
    hits=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from datetime import datetime
from .models import PageView

def index(request):
    if (PageView.objects.count() <= 0):
        x = PageView.objects.create()
        x.save()
    else:
        x = PageView.objects.all()[0]
        x.hits = x.hits + 1
        x.save()
        context = {'page': x.hits}
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context=context)
```

**HTML**

```
 <h4 >You are {{page}}th visitor</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have page_name as well as it's count in the **PageView** model something like this:

```py
from django.db import models
class PageView(models.Model):
    page = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    hits = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now, in the `views.py` you'll need to first fetch the current counter value and then update it.

In **views.py**
**EDIT based on OP's comment to the answer:**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from datetime import datetime
from .models import PageView

def index(request):
    current_page_count = PageView.objects.filter(page=page_name).hits
    context = {'page': current_page_count}

    if not request.session.get('counted'):
        page_view = PageView()
        page_view.hit = current_page_count + 1
        page_view.save()
        context = {'page': page_view.hit}
        request.session['counted'] = True

    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context=context)
```

Once you have counted, you'll need to update the session to indicate that the page_view has already been counted for this session. Now, based on this you can decide whether to update the count.

Comment: i want to count every visit to page as one hit ( meaning one session as one count if i open the page in another tab or browser plus one count despite of what page i visit one session = one hit).

Comment: @DhananjayaDR Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the session anywhere in your code. A simple implementation could be:

```
def index(request):
    if not request.session.get("already_counted"):
        # ...update the counter...
        request.session["already_counted"] = True
    ...
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context=context)
```